Can't log into administrative interface
I installed CiviCRM this afternoon to test some functions out.  I had a lot of issues so I went to go set up Spark instead, but the website was broken and wouldn't accept my
CAPTCHA.  So I went back to work to try and figure out where my issue is.
I have figured out that there is something weird with AuthX and it is related to a user security setting, but since I can't get into the interface, I can't change the authentication methods allowed for the administrator and I've been all over the AuthX module and the software trying to find a workaround or a clue.
Has anyone else had this issue?
I'm using the most recent Git build, and before someone suggests that I roll back, it's taken me the better part of four hours to get where I am.  Any suggestions as to whether I can tweak a database setting or edit a file? I have SSH access to my server and CPanel as well.
--JC

what CMS is involved?

I'm not using a CMS.  Standalone.  I've also deleted the entire folder, I'll try to pull the repository another day because I just tried to install the CLI tool and it freaked out as well...

Down at the bottom of https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/authx/#settings is a purple section that at first glance looks empty because of the weird styling but if you click on it it has some info about how to allow all authx methods for testing. If you don't have cv you can download it from https://github.com/civicrm/cv?tab=readme-ov-file#download

in case standalone is a significant factor i have tagged accordingly
